# Button orientation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, orientation

I create a button programmatically and point its frame to another button that I have created on storyboard, when orientation changes it doesnt stay in middle as it supposed to be.

I also create a `UIImageview` but it stays in the middle when orientation changes

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton* popUpButton;

UIImage *logOutButtonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button - Logout.png"];
    _popUpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_popUpButton setBackgroundImage:logOutButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _popUpButton.frame=_loginButton.frame;
     [_popUpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_popUpButton];
```

Image and button on storyboard, they are in the middle

[image]

image's property

[image]

button'property

[image]

result:

works normal on view `didload` no matter what the orientation is:

[image]

doesnt stay in the middle when orientation changes

[image]

Why button doesn't stay in the middle, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `autoresizing mask`

```
_popUpButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Actually, this will make the button rotate and drift either to the left or the right.

Comment: As i understand your button is at the center at first, and changes origin after rotate. This will help it to stay in the center.

Comment: so when orientation changes it does not update _popupbutton's frame

Comment: It updates the frame, but relativly to start frame and orientation. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html